# Openshift NodeJS + MongoDB application suddenly stops

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

I recently started using OpenShift as a scalable platform for a NodeJS + MongoDB application. I got it all working, except that after some time (mostly within a few hours or days) my application suddenly gets inaccesible. I think there are 2 causes for my app to stop. One cause is that the MongoDB connection times out, which is probably an easy fixable error by checking whether the database is still connected before using the database.

However the other cause is that NodeJS suddenly stops listening to new requests. I am not exactly sure what happens and what the reason for this behaviour is, but when this happens, I have to manually restart the application through ssh, and in a production environment this is unacceptable.

Since I dont get any errors, I can't really provide any more details, except that i (probably) have a scalable app, currently using 2 gears, one for the NodeJS app and one for the MongoDB database. I use MongooseJS to connect to the database. For the time being im still in the free plan, but once more traffic is coming, ill probably go for the silver plan (assuming that scaling actually works).

I hope someone can provide me with some advice or a solution.

Sincerely,

Hylke Bron

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things you should be aware of. The first being Idling, If your application does not receive any external http requests for 48 hours it will be idled. Then once a http request is made the application will come back online automatically.

If you're getting external http requests frequently then the next thing we'll need to check is  the logs for your application. You can check the logs for your app but running `rhc tail <yourappname>`.

Comment: I am aware of the idling, but that is not the case, for it happened tonight again, within 2 hours after a restart of the app because it stopped responding to request, the app again stopped responding to requests. I checked the logs, however not through rhc tail <myappname> but through tail_all when i log into the ssh shell using putty and some key hashes. I assume thats the same, and those logs dont tell me anything. If im checking my log files wronly, please tell me, but i dont see anything weird there.

Comment: Since your app is scalable, the database and the framework are going to be on separate gears. Are you checking the logs on both gears?

If not try running `rhc app show rails4 --gears` and then ssh into your DB gear and see if there are any errors there.

Comment: I tried to ssh into the database gear, but it gave me an identification error, probably because i dont understand how to set the correct private key using putty (im kinda a noob on these things), so if i cant figure it out tomorrow ill let someone come who can. But I used to get notified once the database would be down, i have that logged, and these logs never appear, so i dont think that the database is the problem (but i wont know till i check it ofcourse). So hypothetically, is there a logic easy thing to check if indeed the database isnt the problem?

Comment: I dont see any unusual logs inside my database gear:
`Thu Mar  6 22:07:44.153 [DataFileSync] flushing mmaps took 10231ms  for 6 files`
`Fri Mar  7 03:35:55.269 [conn248]  authenticate db: somevalue { authenticate: 1, user: "somevalue", nonce: "somevalue", key: "somevalue" }`
`Fri Mar  7 03:53:49.409 [DataFileSync] flushing mmaps took 14483ms  for 6 files`