# NodeJS application on openshift gets flooded with empty requests

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am not entirely sure if this is a bad thing or not, but i was monitoring (logging) what incoming http request i get with this piece of code (note that running an NodeJS application on the scalable OpenShift platform):

```
function onRequest(request, response)
{
    var date = new Date();
    console.log(date.toUTCString() + " A request was made with url: " + request.url + " and header: " + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    // continue handling the request
}
```

The results i get are the following (every 2 seconds):

```
 Fri, 07 Mar 2014 09:43:59 GMT A request was made with url: / and header: {}
 Fri, 07 Mar 2014 09:44:01 GMT A request was made with url: / and header: {}
 Fri, 07 Mar 2014 09:44:03 GMT A request was made with url: / and header: {}
```

So i am wondering if this is normal behaviour for a scalable NodeJS app (with a MongoDB database gear attached) in openshift, or is this something that could cause problems?

Sincerely,

Hylke Bron

Comment: Are you using anything to monitor the uptime of your website? (If you do, every two seconds sounds lot anyway).

Comment: Not that i know of, maybe openshift automatically does something like monitoring every 2 seconds. But the more weird thing is that the header information is completely empty, but when i do a request to the server myself, the headers object is filled with data:
`Fri, 07 Mar 2014 09:36:43 GMT A request was made with url: /?action=getData and header: {"content-type":"text/plain;charset=UTF-8","accept":"*/*","accept-encoding":"gzip,deflate,sdch","x-forwarded-proto":"http","x-forwarded-port":"80","x-request-start":"t=1394185003033279"}` (And lots more data, but i removed it becaus of the char limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running a scaled application, then that is haproxy making sure that your application is up so that it can forward requests to it.  You can change haproxy settings in your haproxy/haproxy.cfg file on your main gear.

Comment: Thanks, guess that makes sense. Could this somehow also be related to an issue i have where my nodejs application suddenly stops listening? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234813/openshift-nodejs-mongodb-application-suddenly-stops)

Comment: It should not be, check your app-domain.rhcloud.com/haproxy-status page when it goes down and see what it says.

Comment: Ah that page with alot of data. Is there some page on the openshift website that tells me how to interpret all that data?

Comment: which config variable do i change to make the request period longer?

Answer (score 1):

I am using this method to inform OPENSHIFT that the application is alive

```
app.head("/", function(req, res, next){
    res.status(200).end();
});
```

Comment: Where exactly are you using this middleware. I'm using this in the main app.js file before session method is called. However, with this, the server idles and return 504 gatewat time out error.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't want to mess with haproxy.cfg, I did this and it seems to work.  In your main app, add a middleware function to abort on the ping

```
function ignoreHeartbeat(except) {
   except = except || 0;
   var count = except;
   return function(req, res, next) {
      if (req.headers["x-forwarded-for"])
         return next();

      if (except > 0) {
          if (--count <= 0) {
             count = except;
             return next();
          }
       }

       res.end();
   }

}

app.use(ignoreHeartbeat(1000));
```

Place that code **before** the call to setup the logger (Express 3 example shown below)

```
app.use(express.logger(...))
```

This logs out every 1000th ping.  Set except to 0 or -1 to ignore all the pings.